# SWI-Prolog console code completion?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Code completion works fine inside the SWI Prolog editor window: Meta+/. How can I invoke code completion from the SWI Prolog console window (the window where ?- prompt appears)? (win x64 build)

**Edit:** as suggested below, TAB completes only to the *greatest common prefix*. It doesn't display all (or most common) possibilities nor it cycles through them.

Answer (score 1):

should be TAB, but I'm not entirely satisfied with this.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for me either. I've never found a way to get it to work anywhere in the UI for windows.